# SpatiaLite not complete data on pt_addresses?

Tags: openstreetmap

I have a problem.
Imported OSM in SQLite using spatialite_osm_map
Samples query

```
$select id,name,min(st_distance(geometry,st_point(22.908082,45.763242),0)) from roads limit 1;
564|Strada Muntenia|26.944248068482
```

Is ok, is my street

```
select id,name,min(st_distance(geometry,st_point(22.908082,45.763242),0)) from roads limit 1;
564|Strada Muntenia|26.944248068482
```

Same is ok, is my street again

```
select id,sub_type,name,min(st_distance(geometry,st_point(22.908082,45.763242),0)) from pg_building limit 1;
33042016|yes|Bloc D2|6.50190449190996
```

Is ok, my address is "Strada Muntenia Bloc D2"

I want to get the rest of data for my address, my city is Hunedoara

```
select id,country,city,postcode,street,housename,housenumber from pt_addresses where city like 'Hun%';
NULL
```

?!?!, no city Hunedoara in pt_addreses ??!?!

```
select id,country,city,postcode,street,housename,housenumber from pt_addresses where housename like '%D2%' or housenumber like '2A%' limit 1;
701843031|RO|Deva|330051|Aleea Militarilor||2a
```

Something, but wrong city and street.
I must understand Hunedoara is missing from pt_addresses ?

Comment: I don't know the scheme of your database. However in OSM [Hunedoara](https://www.openstreetmap.org/way/35417927) is mapped as a *town*, not as a *city*. So maybe you need to replace `city` with `town`?

Answer (score 0):

Solved,

curl https://download.geofabrik.de/europe/romania-latest.osm.bz2 --output romania-latest.osm.bz2
bzcat romania-latest.osm.bz2 | bin/osmosis  --read-xml enableDateParsing=no file=-  --bounding-box top=46.104185 left=22.744446 bottom=45.500572 right=24.245453 --write-xml file=-  | bzip2 > hunedoara.osm.bz2

spatialite_osm_raw -o hunedoara.osm -d hunedoara.sqlite
spatialite_osm_map -o hunedoara.osm -d hunedoara.sqlite
spatialite_osm_net -o hunedoara.osm -d hunedoara.sqlite -T roads -m
spatialite_network -d hunedoara.sqlite -T roads -g geometry -c cost -t node_to -f node_from -n name --oneway-fromto oneway_fromto --oneway-tofrom oneway_tofrom -o roads_net_data --overwrite-output
spatialite hunedoara.sqlite 'CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE "roads_net" USING VirtualNetwork("roads_net_data")'

And now database is complete.
SELECT
 way_id, sub, k, v
FROM osm_way_tags  AS ways_ref
WHERE
(
 ways_ref.way_id IN (33042016)
);

---

33042016    0   name    Bloc D2
33042016    1   source  Hunedoara Town Hall map
33042016    2   building    yes
33042016    3   addr:street Strada Muntenia
33042016    4   addr:housename  D2
33042016    5   addr:housenumber    2A

---